# Is there a way to add my own properties in sulu settings tab?

Tags: sulu

I would like to add two optional properties for every page in sulu, the name of a menu-icon and an additional long title for every menu-item. I thought the best place to add those would be the "Settings" tab which shows up when editing an individual page in the admin, underneath the "Show page in" option.

Is there any way to add my own fields to this tab, or do i have to make it an individual property in every page-template? And why isn't the mandatory page-title an option like "Show in page" which doesn't require inclusion in individual page-templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already thought about removing the title from the structure, but it grow that way, and it is not that easy to remove. Apart from that we are not sure if we want that at all, because this way you can place the title in the form where ever you want.

And it is currently not possible to easily add fields to the settings tab. Either you add them to the content tab using the XML files, or you create an own tab for your data as described in the [documentation](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/cookbook/using-tab-navigation.html?highlight=tab).